# how to do multiplication on dynamically added variables in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

i want total amount from price and product quantity dynamically after changing `#quantity` text-box value.
Here is how i did it. but there's no call to `calculate` function as i checked in Firefox console. any solutions?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#quantity").bind('change',calculate);
    function calculate()
    {
    var price = $("#price").val();
    var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
    var amount = price * quantity;
    $("#amount").val(amount);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9AUzy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use format number

```
$.fn.formatNumber = function() {
$(this).keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 109, 110, 189, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
return this;

};
```

Then use keyup:

```
$.fn.setupQty = function() {
$(this).keyup(function(){
    if( $('#quantity').val() != '' && $('#price').val() != '') {
        var quantity = $(this).val();
        var price = $("#price").val();  
        var amount = price * quantity;
        $("#amount").val(amount);
    }
    else {
        $("#amount").val(0);
    }
});
return this;
};
$('#quantity').formatNumber().setupQty();
```